# Please explain types with multiple outputs

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

I understand basic type signatures like

```
myFunction :: Int -> String
myFunction a = "Always produce this string"
```

But in the week 5 lesson, in Free.hs (and similar in the other hs files), I see this type signature (with implementation)

```
mint :: MintParams -> Contract w FreeSchema Text ()
mint mp = do
    let val     = Value.singleton curSymbol (mpTokenName mp) (mpAmount mp)
        lookups = Constraints.mintingPolicy policy
        tx      = Constraints.mustMintValue val
    ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith @Void lookups tx
    void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx
    Contract.logInfo @String $ printf "forged %s" (show val)
```

It appears that the function produces multiple different outputs. I cannot reproduce this structure on my own using simple code such as

```
myAttempt :: Int -> String String
myAttempt a = "Make this" "Make that"
```

This causes the compiler to complain as follows

```
*JWB2> :l JWB2.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling JWB2             ( JWB2.hs, interpreted )

JWB2.hs:48:21: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘String’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature: myAttempt :: Int -> String String
   |
48 | myAttempt :: Int -> String String
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Is this a capability added thru one of the LANGUAGE declarations? Or Plutus modules? A partial function? Unique to do blocks? Related to Monads?

Various searches have not provided an explanation, but I'm sure someone here can!

Answer (score 2):

`String` is a type all by itself so that a type `String String` does not actually make sense.

However, you can return a tuple of values so that your function would be:

```
myAttempt :: Int -> (String, String)
myAttempt _a = ("Make this", "Make that")
```

I added the underscore to `_a` so that the compiler will not give an "unused parameter" warning.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of `Contract w FreeSchema Text ()`. This is one single `Contract` type. `w`, `FreeSchem`, `Text`, and `()` are like parametrisation of the type.

Comment: That makes sense. But I tried to create parallel syntax using more common data types and my own defined data types and I generate syntax errors. Is this because Contract is a Monad?

Answer (score 2):

What about this example:

```
f :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
f x = if odd x then Nothing else Just x
```

Just like here you have `Maybe a` and you replace `a` with `Integer`, in your case you have the (rather complicated) type `Contract w s e a` where some of the type variables have been replaced with values.

You tried to do `String String` but `String` has no variables that you can replace with `String` - therefore the error about the appropriate kinds:

`String :: *`, i.e. String is a type, while `Maybe :: * - *` i.e. you get a type by applying Maybe to a type.